# Передача строки из потока

Tags: c#, winforms

Вопрос таков. Есть класс, который вызывает в процессе работы поток, а именно ресивер, получающий строку. Необходимо отобразить эту строку в основной форме на контрол. Использую Windows Forms.

Comment: Найдите дубликат, кто-нибудь!

Comment: У меня тут есть нюансы. 1) Я не использую return, т.к. это UDP прием, который крутится у меня в вайле. 2)Класс UDP реализован отдельно от формы.

Comment: А чем не подходит решение с `BeginInvoke`?

Comment: Ну после ретурна вайл прекращает работу же.

Comment: Ну так не используйте ретурн, делов-то. У вас есть строка, можно делать BeginInvoke. Вам же не обязательно код копипастить один в один.

Comment: Очевидно, что я задал вопрос по той причине, что не совсем понял механики BeginInvoke.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39670/discussion-between-darrio-and-vladd).